# How to fix a variable in a correlated subquery (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Picked up SQL recently and I am having an issue with a particular correlated subquery.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM videos a
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT NULL
FROM actors b
WHERE a.actor not ilike b.actor
and a.title ilike ('%' + b.actor + '%'));
```

Essentially, I want to find all entries in the video table that has an actor's name in its title, but not tagged as being in that video.  The above code just returns every video in the table, which I'm guessing is because the subquery is not using the same 'b.actor' in both lines.  How can I change it to actually do what I want?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The string concatenation operator in SQL is `||` not  `+`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to use `||` instead of `+` to concatenate strings.
Then, I'd use `LEFT JOIN` to find proper relationships between videos and actors, with `GROUP BY` on video ID and collecting actor IDs (if any) with `array_agg(..)`:

```
select
  v.id as video_id,
  array_agg(a.id) actors_ids
from videos v
left join actors a on 
  v.title ilike ('%' || a.actor || '%')
  and v.actor not ilike a.actor
group by 1
;
```

You can remove rows with empty actors from result set with `HAVING`. Or just use 'INNER JOIN' to get only those videos that have at least proper connection actors:

```
select
  v.id as video_id,
  array_agg(a.id) actors_ids
from videos v
join actors a on 
  v.title ilike ('%' || a.actor || '%')
  and v.actor not ilike a.actor
group by 1
;
```

Finally, this whole approach of using `ILIKE` will be very slow if your tables are big. And not strict -- in many cases you'll have wrong matches (like "John" will match "Johnathan").

Consider Normalization (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) and working either with EAV model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) or with integer arrays or JSONB data type.